# Azure Data Factory: Unable to use inline dataset for Common Data Model, when linked service is parameterized

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-data-factory, dataverse

We are currently using the default export data from [DataVerse to Azure Data Lake](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/powerapps/maker/data-platform/azure-synapse-link-synapse). Then we read the data using the following [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/export-to-data-lake-data-adf). When we specify the inline dataset (CDM) and a linked service that is parameterized, we get an error.

DL Storage Gen2 should be able to handle parameterization, according to MS official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services?tabs=data-factory#supported-linked-service-types). But it seems that inline datasets are not able to handle it.
So how are we supposed to parameterize a linked service when using CI/CD?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Checkout MS doc [Inline datasets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-source#:~:text=When%20a%20format,to%20data%20flow.) and similar [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69656255/15969417)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own solution was to use filetransform step in Azure DevOps to replace the linked service URL.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike native datasets, inline dataset does not have the provision of parameterization. A linked service is used  to link your data store to the service. Linked services are like connection strings, which define the connection information needed for the service to connect to external resources. And dataset represents the structure of the data within the linked data stores, and the linked service defines the connection to the data source.

However, here (Azure synapse linked service) in UI, has a provision for parameterization but dataset when chosen as "inline", they don't match!

I couldn't find a clear documentation on the same, you can consider logging as support request or an issue [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/new/choose) for an official response or share a feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c#), [**similar**](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/bdcef032-6f26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c) one

Comment: My own solution was to use filetransform step in Azure DevOps to replace the linked service URL.

Answer (score 0):

Inline datasets in ADF data flows do not yet support parameterized linked services. That work is currently under way and we are looking to enable that shortly.

Comment: I found that there is a request for that feature here [link](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/bdcef032-6f26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c).